# Carousel Page Indicator

Tags: c#, xamarin, carousel, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms (1.4.2.6359) Project using Visual Studio 2013 and have created the carousel page below. I want to add page indicators, i.e. dots over top of the carousel page. Is this able to be done with the Xamarin Forms CarouselPage?

```
public class SplashPage : CarouselPage
{
    public SplashPage ()
    {
        this.Children.Add(new CarouselChild("Logo.png", "Welcome"));
        this.Children.Add(new CarouselChild("Settings.png", "Settings"));
    }

}

class CarouselChild : ContentPage
{

    public CarouselChild(string image, string text)
    {
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
        layout.Children.Add(new Image
        {
            Source = image,
        });
        layout.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            Text = text,
            Scale = 2,
        });

        this.Content = layout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to keep things simple, what I did was:

[image]

**MyCarouselPage**:

```
class MyCarouselPage : CarouselPage
{
    private int totalPages;
    private int currentPage;

    public MyCarouselPage()
    {
        var pages = GetPages();

        totalPages = pages.Length;

        this.ChildAdded += MyCarouselPage_ChildAdded;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
        {
            currentPage = i;
            this.Children.Add(pages[i]);
        }
    }

    void MyCarouselPage_ChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
    {
        var contentPage = e.Element as MyPageBase;

        if (contentPage != null)
        {
            contentPage.FinalStack.Children.Add(new CarouselPageIndicator(currentPage, totalPages, "indicator.png", "indicator_emtpy.png"));
        }
    }

    private MyPageBase[] GetPages()
    {
        var pages = new MyPageBase[] { new Page1(), new Page2() };
        return pages;
    }
}
```

The **Base** class for the Pages

```
class MyPageBase:ContentPage
{
    public StackLayout FinalStack { get; set; }
}
```

**CarouselPageIndicator**

```
public class CarouselPageIndicator : StackLayout
{
    public CarouselPageIndicator(int currentIndex, int totalItems, string sourceIndicator, string souceEmptyIndicator)
    {
        this.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        this.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
        {
            var image = new Image();

            if (i == currentIndex)
                image.Source = sourceIndicator;
            else
                image.Source = souceEmptyIndicator;

            this.Children.Add(image);
        }

        this.Padding = new Thickness(10);
    }
}
```

And for the **n-Pages**

```
class Page1:MyPageBase
{
    public Page1()
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label{Text="Page 1"}
            }
        };

        this.FinalStack = layout;

        this.Content = FinalStack;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a work around for the problem by hard coding the page indicators by changing CarouselChild method below:

```
public CarouselChild(string image, string text, int pageNumber, int pageCount)
    {
        var width = this.Width;
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness( 40, 40, 40, 40),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
        };
        layout.Children.Add(new Image
        {
            Source = image,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        });
        layout.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Text = text,
            FontSize = 36,
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
        });
        layout.Children.Add(CarouselPageIndicator(pageNumber, pageCount));

        this.Content = layout;
    }

    internal StackLayout CarouselPageIndicator(int pageNumber, int pageCount)
    {
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
        };

        if (pageCount >= pageNumber)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < pageCount + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == pageNumber)
                {
                    layout.Children.Add(new Image
                    {
                        Source = "Light.png",
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    layout.Children.Add(new Image
                    {
                        Source = "Dark.png",
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return layout;
    }
```

Comment: one question...this code is for each child of the carousel?

Comment: @Fran_gg7 Yes, this is the code for each page of a tabbed page layout. You can modify the CarouselChild as needed. This is my implementation: Android App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cookdata.mycarcare
iOS App: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-car-care/id978927751